# location.reload esta bloqueando descarga de contenido?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta porcion de codigo que despues de un submit enviando una lista de registros seleccionados simplemente scrollea hacia arriba con un mensaje, el navegador espera una descarga de pdf generada del lado del servidor, cuestion que cuando hago un setTimeout y un reload de la pagina no se descarga nada, pero cuando comento ese setTimeOut funciona todo okey, el problema es que si o si necesito recargar la pagina para mostrarle al usuario los row que ya no estan disponibles en la lista

```
$("#btnGenerar").click(function (e) {
        if (confirm('¿Está seguro que desea generar los certificados para las solicitudes seleccionadas?')) {
            $('#hf-accion').val('generar');
            $("#CertificadoSemillas").submit();

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
            $('#divError').removeClass("alert-danger");
            $('#divError').removeClass("hide");
            $('#divError').text("Se han generado los certificados de manera exitosa");
            $('#divError').addClass("alert-success");
            
            setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.reload(1);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar un ejemplo de la tabla y el código de envío del formulario, sería mejor eliminar las filas que se seleccionaron.

Comment: ¡Ah! La respuesta a tu pregunta es: Sí, si el navegador está realizando la descarga y cambias la ubicación o recargas la página actual, termina la petición anterior.

Comment: efectivamente era eso, no le doy tiempo al servidor de terminar la peticion y estoy interrumpiendo el proceso por detras

Answer (score 1):

¿el submit del form es lo que genera la descarga del pdf?
Puedes probar a que la respuesta del form sea en otra página:

```
form=$("#CertificadoSemillas");
$(form).prop('target','_blank');
$(form).submit();
```

Si eso no te funciona, puedes evitar la recarga de la página actualizando los datos de la tabla mediante ajax.

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

parece ser que del lado del servidor no termina de generar el pdf que la pagina se recarga, osea el settimeout tiene que ser mas largo porque sino interrumpe todo el proceso del backend